# Unity3D swipe controls to increment counter (C#)

Tags: c#, touch, unity-game-engine, swipe

I've looked around for various swiping-related answers, and could not find anything that suited me directly.

The idea is to swipe left to increment an integer variable, and left to decrement it. I have it working for buttons, and would simply like to convert it for a touch input.

The current script is as follows:

```
private void Buttons(){
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (1080,80, 40, 220), "Next")) {
        screenNumber ++;
    }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (160,80, 40, 220), "Back")) {
        screenNumber --;
    }       
}
```

*screenNumber is the name of the int variable.

I am developing for Android, if that is important for this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/141664-Swipe-Gesture

Comment: That unfortunately is JS, C# would be ideal.

Comment: JavaScript/C# conversion is trivial. I'm sure if you put _some_ effort into it you could make-do.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [FingerGestures](http://fingergestures.fatalfrog.com/) for both mouse and touch controls. I highly recommend it, especially for painless Touch/Mobile development.